# Error when trying to make clockType class problem

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn classes and I wrote this code to set, get and print the time for class clockType. The code compiles, however, I am not getting my desired output. Please help me spot the error. The following is my code. I am getting output 0:0:0.

I made one default constructor, constructor, setTime function, getT

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    #include <string>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class clockType
    {
        private : 
            int hr, min, sec;
    
        public:
            clockType(int hr, int min, int sec)
            {
                if (0 <= hr && hr < 24)
                    hr = hr;
                else
                    hr = 0;
                if (0 <= min && min < 60)
                    min = min;
                else
                    min = 0;
                if (0 <= sec && sec < 60)
                    sec = sec;
                else
                    sec = 0;
            }
    
            clockType()
            {
                hr = 0;
                min = 0;
                sec = 0;
            }
    
            void setTime(int hr, int min, int sec)
            {
                if (0<= hr && hr< 24)
                    hr = hr;
                else hr= 0;
    
                if ( 0 <= min && min <60)
                    min = min;
                else min = 0; 
    
                if ( 0 <= sec && sec<60)
                    sec = sec ;
                else sec  = 0; 
            }
            void getTime(int& hr, int& min, int& sec)
            {
                hr = hr;
                min = min;
                sec = sec; 
    
            }
            void printTime()
            {
            
                    cout << hr << ":";
                
                    cout << min << ":";
                
                    cout << sec;
            }
    
    
    };
    
    int main()
    
    {
        clockType myClock;
    
        myClock.setTime(5, 2, 30);
    
        myClock.printTime();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In your `setTime` function, what variable is used when you use e.g. `hr`? The *argument* variable, or the *member* variable? You can only pick *one* of them (and one of the alternatives is wrong).

Comment: `hr = hr;` -- That confuses me, that should also confuse you.  Which `hr` is being assigned to which `hr`?  The same thing with the other lines that look like this, i.e. `min = min;`

Comment: The member var. `hr` is eclipsed by the argument `hr`. You can circumvent this (and access both) by using `this->hr` which addresses explicitly the member var. (The `this->` is used implicitly but only if there is no better candidate. A local var. or arg. _is_ a better candidate but you still have the option to use `this->` explicitly.) Thus, `this->hr = hr;` assigns _arg._ `hr` to _member var._ `hr`. (Respectively with `min` and `sec`.)